# If everything ends one day why don't we end it today?

Tags: existence, meaning-of-life

Is there any doctrine that gives the reason why to wait till the end of the world?

I'm 18 and not depressed.

I am not asking about the purpose of life. I'm asking why should we fulfill the purpose of the result or anything related to the purpose shall ultimately perish. Hence in a more direct way, I'm asking why should we fulfill the purpose. The question might sound like *If God is the world then who created God and then who created the creator of God and so on*. The question is not self-recursive but rather passive and seeking why fulfills the purpose.

My opinion says either there is nothing like complete or even if there is then we should fulfill the purpose to push the END as further as possible, something like RPG we know someone will defeat us but longer can we endure is the whole aim.

Comment: Hedonism, for instance. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pleasure/. Otherwise, go to the movies, get a ticket, and as soon the movie starts ask yourself: "if the movie will end, why don't I just leave the room right now?"

Comment: @RodolfoAP if I knew that ultimately i will die and there is no point of living why would I be living. But I can't know without living whether it was worth living or not

Comment: @HaPenny now I get your question. You are not a victim of life, a passive observer. You decide what to do and what to get from life, you are the architect of your destiny, the one who makes wishes realise. Most people decide to get happiness, and they just get it. Don't be a victim. Even people who survived (and not) nazi extermination camps lived free and happy. In such horrible conditions. Read Viktor Frankl's _Man's Search for Meaning_.

Comment: Welcome to philosophy.stackexchange.com. If you feel depressed and need someone to talk, please be open about it, and seek help with direct dialogue, possibly also a medical professional. This forum (like most of the internet) is not suitable to help with depression.
Apart from being too broad and opinion based, the question should be closed also as duplicate for many other questions under the meaning-of-life tag: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-of-life . If none of the existing questions was enough, please be more specific.

Comment: @tkruse I'm not depressed and don't make me depressed i wished to know if this aspect is explored or not my observation says we should exist to push the end.

Comment: Because the way is the goal. Even if something ends, we still can/want to enjoy it while it lasts. This includes our life.

Comment: This is essentially the famous is-ought problem for moral actions...

Comment: A most moving thought. Kudos! You might be required to prove something which I fear very few except the crème de la crème can.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously all major religions claim that life has a meaning, typically the purpose of gaining benefits after this life from doing good deeds. Typically the rewards are for all eternity in paradise, so the rewards never perish, even if maybe the world ends.

Religions typically are not clear about the purpose of the purpose, why any god would care about us going to paradise after plenty of good deeds. This would be for experts in a given religion to answer. But fantasy can make up so kinds of reasons for paradise.

If you select a worthy cause in life yourself as opposed to a religion, such as saving the rainforest, or becoming rich, then typically the idea would be to not care about the infinite future, but only about the imminent future. I cannot think of any external non-spriritual purpose that would remain meaningful once the world ends.

Without a spiritual purpose, your life is more like a ticket to spend a day in an amusement park one day before you die. Nothing you will do will change anything in the long run, you only have the choice of using the ticket to enjoy the day, or to not go and stay in bed.

There is no further meaning or purpose or reason. Or at least i never heard of anyone having found such a purpose that seems meaningful in the infinite.

Comment: you are really taking altogether different meaning. I am not seeking why we exist! I'm seeking if we exist and if it is certain that we will perish what's make difference if perish today or tomorrow. Your answer explains existence may have purpose. I am reposing that even that purpose will perish and so why we fulfil the purpose?

Comment: I changed my answer. Paradise maybe never perishes, else there is no known purpose, but people can imagine anything they like

Comment: Now I agree with you. But to just an strech, even being at amusement park helps me to get new experiences despite visiting with out a motto some unknown purpose is still being fulfilled. Any information collected there could help to prevent or amend the bad.So at end even a pre-planned futile visit could significantly garner an undesired purposes and conclusions

Comment: What if you know you are going to die the next day, so you can choose between a day in the amusement park and then death, or immediate death.

Comment: you assume we know at what date i'm dying. But in reality we don't! Just imagine some Hitman said he will shoot anytime within a week how painful would it be to wait him to kill i'll die too many times again and again before he actually kills me.

Comment: We know we're going to die one day, and until then we have a ticket for the amusement park that is life.

Comment: @tkruse But do we *really* know?

Comment: @Andy if I don't die, then I guess I'll be pleasantly surprised. Unless I end up in that room with those other people...

Comment: @ScottRowe At what point in time will you be pleasantly surprised though?

Comment: @Andy this explains the epidemic of depression: people never get around to being happy.

Answer (score 1):

But also, why end it? This is the perspective taken up by Absurdism

> "Should I kill myself, or have a cup of coffee? But in the end one
> needs more courage to live than to kill himself." - Camus

I would say even in the face of troubles, it only takes curiosity to have sufficient motivation to continue. So I think cultivating curiosity is very valuable.

The most convincing argument though I think, is that of mysticism. What really is meaning, what does why mean, addressed in the mystic sense of direct observation of our own minds and exploration of unusual ways to think and be, help to catch some of the processes by which we construct the world, and to realise that there is something unconditioned about our minds, something that precedes all the construction work of motivations and meanings. And we can situate our approach to life from there, once we become familiar with that place.

> "When … you realize that you live in, that indeed you are this moment
> now, and no other, that apart from this there is no past and no
> future, you must relax and taste to the full, whether it be pleasure
> or pain. At once it becomes obvious why this universe exists, why
> conscious beings have been produced, why sensitive organs, why space,
> time, and change. The whole problem of justifying nature, of trying to
> make life mean something in terms of its future, disappears utterly.
>
> Obviously, it all exists for this moment. It is a dance, and when you
> are dancing you are not intent on getting somewhere… The meaning and
> purpose of dancing is the dance."
>
> -Alan Watts

> "At the still point of the turning world. Neither flesh nor fleshless;
> Neither from nor towards; at the still point, there the dance is, But
> neither arrest nor movement. And do not call it fixity, Where past and
> future are gathered. Neither movement from nor towards, Neither ascent
> nor decline. Except for the point, the still point, There would be no
> dance, and there is only the dance."
>
> -TS Eliot

> "And there might not be a sadder thing
>
> Than watchin' Saturn lose her rings
>
> And black holes slowly dancing in the dark
>
> It's a song that they were born to sing
>
> About the end of everything
>
> Until it all goes up in one last spark
>
> Everyone you love is gonna die
>
> But so is everything so
> wipe your eyes
>
> You know nothin' lasts forever, but Lord, I try
>
> And
> everyone you love is gonna die
>
> All the saints and sinners are the same
>
> We're blessed and we obliterate
>
> And that's how it was written from the
> start
>
> It's a song that we were born to sing
>
> About the end of everything"
>
> -Noah Cyrus

Comment: A really appreciable answer. Can you who is Noah Cyrus? Google tells that she is singer.

Comment: @Ha'Penny: Yes, that song is called 'The End Of Everything'. Miley Cyrus' littlest sister, she is from Generation Z, those born after the Millenium, and I think it shows.

Comment: @Ha'Penny you should check *The Myth of Sisyphus*, a book that addresses precisely your question. Or rather, commentaries about the book itself, because it is quite confusing for beginners. +1 for bringing up Camus.

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, we simply wanted to minimise suffering, and knew that suffering is unavoidable in life, we might consider that ending all life immediately would be the best way forward.  However, philosophy aside, from an evolutionary standpoint all living organisms have a strong will to survive and possibly for no better reason than that organisms with a lesser will to survive are now extinct.  To that extent it is not a question of philosophy, which allows us to ask and answer questions that aren’t necessarily in our best interests, but rather an observation that we are who we are because of the path that has brought us here.

Comment: Antinatalism holds the view being alive is a net-negative experience. "all living organisms have a strong will to survive" Replicators that replicate more, replicate more. So, sure the future will be populated by those with a bias to see it as worthwhile to continue. But that doesn't answer why you should be one of those. As creatures with minds not just genes, we can make up our own minds, we don't have to be coerced by biology.

Comment: @CriglCragl absolutely, but we will have a predisposition towards survival; I’m stating this without proposing that it makes any sense at an individual level.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of quotes from Al Alvarez's [The Savage God: A Study of Suicide](https://books.google.gg/books?id=aGBLQAbPE7cC&pg=PA88), page 88 & 90

> Augustine took over Plato’s and the Pythagoreans’ argument that life
> is the gift of God, and our sufferings, being divinely ordained, are
> not to be foreshortened by one’s own actions; to bear them patiently
> is a measure of one’s greatness of soul.  Thus, to take one’s own life
> proved only that one did not accept the divine will. ...
>
> St. Thomas Aquinas sealed up the whole question in the *Summa*: suicide,
> he said, is a mortal sin against God, who has given life; it is also a
> sin against justice and against charity.  Yet even there, in what was
> to be the center of Christian doctrine, Aquinas takes his arguments
> from non-Christian sources.  The sin against God derived ultimately,
> like Augustine’s similar argument, from Plato.  The sin against
> justice—by which he means the individual’s responsibilities to his
> community—harks back to Aristotle.  As for the sin against charity,
> Aquinas means that instinctive charity which each men bears toward
> himself—that is, the instinct of self-preservation which man has in
> common with the lower animals; to go against that is a mortal sin,
> since it is to go against nature.

Comment: i extremely dislike idea of God creating us to test us. Indirectly it yields we are doll in hand of narcissist who wants his dolls to worship him follow his guidelines and which doesn't he executes them. Might sound bit harsh, but I think our God didn't created us to worship him. If he did then our God worse than a human.

Comment: In Augustine's defence, he did come up with that to stop the early Christian Donatists killing themselves at the earliest opportunity to avoid sin and guarantee passage to Heaven.  (As described in the link.)

Comment: link shows not accessible just to pg 88

Comment: @Ha'Penny - The early Christians and Donatists are on page 85 to 88.

Answer (score 0):

> If everything ends one day why don't we end it today?

Because we have not learned to end it today.

I take it that people are mechanistic under behaviorist philosophy. Part of that implies that people are learning machines. Granted, I don't think that anyone has libertarian free will to commit suicide. Instead, taking one's life would be a behavioral response to having learned to do such.

So, "luck" or "happenstance" are driving factors. Sure, there are things that are correlated with taking one's life, but those things at best only influence the decision-making process. My presumption is that when escape becomes "accepted" as impossible, such as escape from a life-sentence in prison that brings about pain and suffering, then motivation to die becomes prevalent, such that the decision-making process to take one's life is initiated.

Given the resources to take one's life, the person who has had the decision-making process initiated that is biased in favor of life ending will take his or her life. The person will have "learned" to end it.

Comment: Suicide is correlated with having other family members previously do that. Parents especially.